# How to generate CRUD (Gii) in Yii2 with PHPmyadmin database data

Tags: phpmyadmin, yii2, yii2-basic-app, gii

I'm studying and developing some tasks to learn Yii2 framework, but stucked in this point:

My database is PHPmyadmin and Yii2 is fully integrated with him, accessing the data, reading, writing, etc. well, integrated till now.

When I generated a CRUD with Gii the Create works, Update works and Delete works, but the reading no. I'm receiving the message 
`The table does not exist: {{%name_of_my_table_search}}`

Searching in the generated errors I discovered that Yii is intering in the following If, in other words, he cannot get the table name im my schema:

```
public static function getTableSchema()
    {
        $tableSchema = static::getDb()
            ->getSchema()
            ->getTableSchema(static::tableName());

        if ($tableSchema === null) {
            throw new InvalidConfigException('The table does not exist: ' . static::tableName());
        }

        return $tableSchema;
}
```

This code above is part of `ActiveRecord` Yii2's default file.

Can anyone help me how to show my table's name  to Yii?

P.S. I dont know how code I can post here to exemplify since all the action is done automatically by the Gii.

Comment: **but the reading no. I'm receiving the message** what does this mean, do you want to say that the `actionView` is throwing the error? and please add the full stack trace in your Post

Comment: show the code you are using for accessing   for the "reading " ..